# SQLite onUpgrade not called

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm checking the update process of an application and onUpgrade is not called.
I do know that `getWritableDatabase();`or 
 `getReadableDatabase();`
should be executed in order for onUpgrade to be called and that DB_VERSION should be incremented.

```
private DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}
```

I've installed the current released version of the app in an emulator and executed:

```
pragma user_version;
```

For some reason it returns **0** although the DB version of the source code of this version is **13**.
In the new version I've updated the DB version to 20 for testing, and after I install the update, using 
`adb install -r myapp.apk`
the DB version is 20 (using the same `pragma user_version;`), but onUpgrade is not called.

This process is usually quite straightforward, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

**Does someone have an idea what's wrong? why the user_version of the current version is 0 and why onUpgrade is not called?**

This is the DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "db_name.db3";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

private static DBHelper sInstance;

public static int DB_VERSION = 20;

public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}


private DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    try {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
        } else {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}


private boolean checkDataBase() {

    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {

        String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                .replace("files", "databases")
                + File.separator + DB_NAME;

        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }

    return checkdb;

}


public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            .replace("files", "databases")
            + File.separator + DB_NAME;
    if (myDataBase == null) {
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } else {
        if (myDataBase.isOpen()) {
            return myDataBase;
        } else {
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
    }

    return myDataBase;
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBaseForWrite() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            .replace("files", "databases")
            + File.separator + DB_NAME;
    if (myDataBase == null) {
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } else {

        if (myDataBase.isOpen()) {
            if (myDataBase.isReadOnly()) {
                myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            } else {
                return myDataBase;
            }
        } else {
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
    }

    return myDataBase;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //NOT CALLED

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more of your DBHelper class.

Comment: Added DBHelper class

Comment: It looks like you are doing some manual file creation for the DB.  I have never moved the files around so I would guess that you are missing an override somewhere in there.   I personally would just let the app create the DB in its default location, but you may have your reasons.

Comment: Yes, it's a pre-generated database that is part of the apk.
I don't think I'm missing an override because if I will increment the DB_VERSION in debug I will hit the onUpgrade method.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the [source code of SQLiteOpenHelper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java), I partially understand the issue and @slackwars assumption was spot on.

Seems onUpgrade will be called only if user_version != 0.

```
if (version != mNewVersion){
 ...

 if (version == 0) {
     onCreate(db);
 } else {
        if (version > mNewVersion) {
            onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
        } else {
            onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
        }
 }
 db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
```

I'm not sure why it's 0, but I've used this to create a workaround using onCreate and solve this issue.